# Running multiple scripts in Google Sheets for Dropdown Lists

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to coding and having some difficulties. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I made a dropdown in Google Sheets where I can select multiple dropdown items. I have one running correctly in Column J (10) but would like to do the same in Columns K and L (11 and 12).

I'm pretty certain  that I need to define the columns but not sure how to do that correctly.
It's executing one and a time and not all at once. How do I fix the code below to allow for each to execute? Would I be including it all in the same script or execute multiple scripts?

Thanks again for the help.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  multipleSelectionDropdown(e)
}

function multipleSelectionDropdown(e) {
  //Grab information about the user's whereabouts
  var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()
  var activeRow = activeCell.getRow()
  var activeCol = activeCell.getColumn()
  var activeSheet = activeCell.getSheet()
  var activeSheetName = activeSheet.getName()
  var newValue = e.value
  var oldValue = e.oldValue

  //See if the user is where I want him to be
  const COL_DROPDOWN = 10;
  const STARTING_ROW_DROPDOWN = 3
  const NAME_SHEET_DROPDOWN = "2024"

  if (activeCol == COL_DROPDOWN && activeRow >= STARTING_ROW_DROPDOWN && activeSheetName == NAME_SHEET_DROPDOWN) {
    //Execute the code
    if(newValue=="" || !newValue) activeCell.setValue("")
    else if(oldValue=="" || !oldValue) activeCell.setValue(newValue)
    else{
      if(oldValue.indexOf(newValue)==-1) activeCell.setValue(oldValue + ", " + newValue)
      else activeCell.setValue(oldValue)
     
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/multiple-dependent-drop-downs

Comment: Check the data validation of your dropdown cell. Make sure that it is not rejecting the input and rather showing a warning if data is invalid. Invalid data for a dropdown means that the value shown is not one of the options. In this case, as you want to show concatenation of multiple selected items, so data will be invalid and so we need data validation to show a warning and not reject the input. Once this setting is changed, I guess it should work if your code is correct. May be it worked for the other two columns because of this.